# If the $f$ and $g$ are integrable, their squares are in $L^{1}$, then is $fg$ in L^{1}?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f, \; g \in L^{+}$ and $f^{2}, \; g^{2} \in L^{1}(\mu),$ then is it true that $fg \in L^{1}(\mu)$?

I know that if I can show that if either $f$ or $g$ is uniformly bounded by some $M$, then I can show this.  However, I am not sure that that is implied by $f^{2} \in L^{1}(\mu)$.

I also want to use that since $L^{1}$ is a vector space, then $fg = \frac{1}{2}((f+g)^{2} - f^{2} - g^{2})$, but I would need to show that $(f+g)^{2} \in L^{1}(\mu)$.

Comment: Use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show this directly :

$$\begin{align} .\int_\Omega |fg| d \mu 
& = \int_{\{|f| > |g|\}} |fg| d\mu + \int_{\{|f| \leq |g|\}} |fg| d\mu\\
& \leq \int_{\{|f| > |g|\}} |f|^2 d\mu + \int_{\{|f| \leq |g|\}} |g|^2 d\mu\\
& \leq \int_\Omega |f|^2 d\mu + \int_\Omega |g|^2 d\mu 
\end{align}$$

And you can also use this idea to show that $(f+g)^2$ is integrable (but it's not easier)